# Debounce doesn't trigger function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am working on a React component and I want to have `debounce` bound to input. My code is as follows:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.deb = this.deb.bind(this);
  }
  ...

  this.deb() {
    debounce(() => { console.log('bam'); }, 400, false);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        onChange={this.deb}
        />
    )
  }
}
```

Without `debounce` in `this.deb` everything works. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`debounce` creates a new debounced version of the function you pass in, so you just need to do it once in the constructor in this case:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deb = debounce(this.deb.bind(this), 400, false);
  }

  deb() {
    console.log('bam');
  }

  render() {
    return <input onChange={this.deb} />;
  }
}
```